# Checking if my array of pointer string is an integer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

EDIT -> My problem with finding if was an integer got solved. My next problem is how to get the size of the array.
Example:

char **str = [hello][world] -> returns 2

char **str = [hello] -> return 1

char **str = [hello][world][yes] -> returns 3

The way I am doing right now. It's wrong

```
int size = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]);
I also tried
int size = sizeof(str) / sizeof(char *);
```

.....

---

I have a program that gets a line from the user like "Hello World".
Then I parse that into an array of pointers: so it's something like `char **str = [Hello][World]`.

Then I want to check if the second index is an integer or not. So if the user types `Hello 2`, this function returns true (1), but if not returns false(0).

I am a little confused how to work with pointers.

So I think I will have something like this:

```
int my_function(char** str) {
    // it's empty
    if (str[0] == NULL)
        return 0;

    // Just have one index
    int size = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]);
    if (size < 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    // checking if data in second index is an integer
    int length = strlen(str[1]);
  
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Here is my problem how do I go over each character for 
        // only str[1] to check if is an integer???????
        if (!isdigit(str)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: So basically you want to check whether the first thing after the space is a `char` or an `int`?

Comment: p20xx, Note: "0", "-123", "+123", "-123", "123456789012345678901234567890", "0xFACE" are all examples of _integers_.  "-+123", "123xyz", "", "zxc" are not.

Comment: The way you calculate the `size` is wrong.

Comment: @alex01011 thank for seeing that. How should I calculate the size then?

Comment: @p20xx You do not calculate the size.  Pass the size into `my_function()` from the calling code.  Post the code that does "I have a program that gets a line" to so we can get an idea of how code is using `my_function()`.

Comment: Regarding `size`. The interresting question is **what do you expect that code to do**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a double dereference. The first dereference to get the relevant char pointer. The second dereference to get the relevant character.

Try:

```
isdigit(str) -->  isdigit(str[1][i])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to help but it did not work. I get error: implicitly declaring library function 'isdigit' with type 'int (int)'

Comment: @p20xx Add `#include <ctype.h>`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
    char *secondString = str[1];
    int length = strlen(secondString );
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length ; ++i)
    {
    if (!isdigit(secondString[i]))
    return 0;
    }

return 1;
```